# How to solve a system of ordinary differential equations contain a interpolating function?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm wondering how I can solve a system of ODE that has a interpolating function? For example, `z` and `y` are `InterpolatingFunction`s generated by prior `NDSolve` commands.  Now I need to solve a second ODE system:

```
{x2'[t] == -k1*x2[t]*y[t]/h2[t] + k2*z[t],
 h2'[t] == -3*(-k1*x2[t]*y[t]/h2[t] + k2*z[t]),
 x2[0] == 0, h2[0] == 1}
```

where `k1` and `k2` are constants.

Comment: I recommend that you post two separate questions. Having said that, I think that both questions have issues. In your first question, you've got a condition on `x`, namely `x[0]==.001`, yet there's no `x[t]` in your system.  Also, concrete explanations as to where `y`, `z`, `k1`, and `k2` arise would be nice. As for the second question - is that well formed mathematically? For example, $f(t)=c e^{-t}$ solves $f'=-f$ and $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}f(t)=0$ for all $c$.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'll post another question regarding to the 2nd part of my question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using an interpolating function in a call to `NDSolve` is a simple matter.  Here's a totally made up example.

```
Clear[x, y];
y[t_] = y[t] /. First[NDSolve[{
      y'[t] == Sin[t] y[t] Sin[y[t]],
      y[0] == 1
      }, y[t], {t, 0, 10}]];
x[t_] = x[t] /. First[NDSolve[{
      x'[t] == y[t]*Sin[x[t]] + 1, x[0] == 1},
     x[t], {t, 0, 10}]];
Plot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Cute. I think it might be worth remarking that a single `NDSolve` call for coupled system would be as efficient.